# JQuery - Replace Underscore With Space

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have the following html and I want to replace underscores with spaces for all anchor tags that appear inside a div with class `xyz`

```
<div class="xyz">
  <b><a>Hello_1</a></b>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
   <b><a>Hello_2</a></b>
</div>
```

The following doesnt work?

```
$('.xyz').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);

   $this.find('a').text().replace(/_/g, ' '));
});
```

Comment: Does `replace("_", ' ')` not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with the regex. You are not updating the text in DOM.
`.text()` gives the `textContent` of an element, it doesn't set it. You can use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) setter as follow

```
$('.xyz a').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/_/g, ' ');
});
```

```js
$('.xyz a').text(function(i, text) {
  return text.replace(/_/g, ' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="xyz">
  <b><a>Hello_1</a></b>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
  <b><a>Hello_2</a></b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to substitute the text that you changed

```
$('.xyz').each(function() {
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
       var newText = $(this).text().replace(/_/g, ' ');
       $(this).text(newText);
  });

});
```

**edited after comments**

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be...

```
var newText = $this.find('a').text().replace(/_/g, ' '));
$(this).find('a').text(newText);
```

It's a bit of an expensive way to traverse the DOM usig find in a loop. You could loop through and put all of your anchor tags into an array first perhaps too depending on the number of anchor tags there are.

Comment: If there's more than one `a`, this will set the text of all them to the first one.   (which is also an issue with the OPs code).

Comment: @freedomn-m There isn't more than one <a> in the example given.

Comment: "for **all** anchor tags that appear inside a div with class" - implies there may be more than one, just not in the example.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes in the example given, the question states 'I have the following html'... I provided a solution that would work with 'the following html'. Would you prefer we all also provide answers for different hypothetical scenarios?

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not gonna get into semantics but it's fairly obvious that OP is alluding to all anchor tags in their provided html structure. I know it's a Monday morning buddy but no need to be such a grumpus.

Comment: I was merely pointing out the *potential* issue with OPs code.

Comment: I disagree that it's "obvious" that an answer should only work for the specific example given and will always point out potential issues.  SO answers are meant to help people **in the future** with a similar issue.  While I agree we obviously we can't handle all scenarios, we can point out obvious issues / potential gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Replace dom element after loop.

```js
$('.xyz').each(function() {
   var $this =  $(this).find('a');
   $this.text( $this.text().replace(/_/g, ' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="xyz">
  <b><a>Hello_1</a></b>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
   <b><a>Hello_2</a></b>
```